# How to configure LAN IPs and subnets for this topology?

Tags: ip, subnet, wired-networking

I have a server that has 1G and 10G links, and a 1G + 10G switch. I want to be able to use the 1G and 10G links simultaneously - either to test both against each other, or to command via SSH on one while testing on the other. This is roughly the topology I'd like to have. But I'm not sure how best to set up two links in parallel between the devices, and getting them treated as distinct without conflicts or issues.

This is the simplified topology I want:

[image]

Because concrete outcomes might help

- I want to be able to run SSH from the PC to the server on my 1G connection, so that I can hammer the 10G link hard via SCP/Samba, or reconfigure it, and test it thoroughly.
- I want to also keep my SSH session live and visible, and compare simultaneous traffic outcomes for identical traffic sent between the same endpoints via the 1G and 10G lines.
- I want to utterly control which link data is sent on, from the client. For example, I want to be able to ping SERVER-1 or send a file via SCP/Samba, and if I get a reply, be sure the data went via SWITCH-3 and not via SWITCH-4 -> SERVER-2 -> SERVER-1 and was actually bridged at the server.
- Ideally the PC should consider the two server IPs as separate devices and not realise they are the same machine. (I won't be sending anything pathological on the two links, where there could be a conflict if SERVER-1 and SERVER-2 were configured to act as if, in effect, they were links to two separate servers and not the one same server). Likewise the server should see the two links from the PC as separate datastreams, perhaps from separate PCs.
- Finally so I can connect and disconnect the file share link but keep a constant PC + internet connection via the 1G link.

I'm not sure about the implications of parallel links like this, or what I need to do to segregate them completely. The server runs FreeBSD 11 if it helps.

For part of the testing it would just really help to have 2 links to the server, one to manage and one to test (break!), that don't interact with or route through each other even though they link the same 2 hosts.

I've considered giving them separate subnets (SERVER-1 @ 10.1.0.0/24 and SERVER-2 @ 10.2.0.0/24) but I'm not sure how far I need to go, to create the effect I'm after. I don't have VLANs working on the LAN right now, so if that would be a solution, it isn't really one I can use today.

**Update**

The "switch" is a pfSense platform so its FreeBSD 11 with  2 x dual 10G SFP+ Chelsio NICs for now. It'll never do line rate and I know that's not its target role, but with a lightweight ruleset it can push Samba packets around at 4.5 Gbps rock solid on 2 different links simultaneously for ad-hoc testing or to replace blown 10G gear while buying a replacement, which is enough for what I'm doing, as its home lab/experimental rather than production.

So it can do whatever `pf` + Chelsio on-card firmware can do, which makes it highly flexible. But I'd have thought there is a standard way to set this up, so I'm intrigued.

The background is, my main 10G switch just died, and I'm taking some time to do overdue troubleshooting/tuning for now, learn some new things,  and do some testing, which is why I don't need more bandwidth and why this is fine until ready to replace the switch in a month or so.

Comment: Please edit question with brand and model of the switch, so we can google manuals etc. Depending on what the switch does exactly, it might not be possible in this configuration at all, and you may have to experiment with the two links without a switch.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to set a distinct IP on each of the server NICs. A switch has no idea what device(s) any given IP belongs to, it just knows about the MAC address, so with two NICs, you have two MACs and therefore two distinct end-points for the switch to send traffic to.

Comment: Is there are reason to choose one IP over the other? Couldn't you dual-stack and use both IPs? That way if requests come in for IPv4, you can natively support that, or if requests come in for IPv6, you can natively support that. Trying to connect to a device that only supports one IP with the other IP can get very ugly. The switch (ethernet) doesn't care which one, or both, IPs it carries.

Comment: @Ron - I'm testing and troubleshooting. The entire aim isn't failover or arbitrary requests coming in (other than those I myself send). Its to have a dedicated management link and a dedicated test/data link - and the machines not getting confused by having 2 routes between them, and not internally bridging the NICs so I think the data went via one route when it didn't. I could give the 2nd li k its own subnet, but for ease I'd like them to be on the same subnet if possible - but is it possible?

Comment: The two different IPs are separate protocols, and they cannot communicate without some type of kludge. and IPv4 host cannot directly communicate with an IPv6 host. That is why you dual-stack your server.

Comment: Ahh. Okay. I don't have any use for IPv6 on the WAN. It didn't occur to me to use it to segregate traffic. Of course it would work..... That's a good tip, which I should have figured but didn't (as I just never use IPv6 or 6to4 here)

Comment: Well, your question asks about IPs, and there are only two current IPs: IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, all you need to do is assign each of your NIC's a distinct IP address, which can be done either staticly or via DHCP. Then just make sure you use the correct IP when communicating with the server.

For example if you configure NIC 1 as `192.168.10.101` and NIC 2 as `192.168.10.202` then:

- Both NICs would be on the same LAN
- Traffic destined for `192.168.10.101` would always go via SWITCH 3 <-> SERVER 1
- Traffic destined for `192.168.10.202` would always go via SWITCH 4 <-> SERVER 2

If you have a local DNS server setup you could create separate host entries for each IP to make it easier to direct traffic.

Comment: The concern is this. Suppose I do that, then ping SVR1 or use \\SVR1 (samba share). Could traffic go PC->SW4->SVR2-> SVR1 invisibly bridging at the server (if SVR1 is disconnected), or be routed that way due to low 10G latency (when both routes are available)? Equally, what if SVR uses CURL to dl from a LAN/WAN machine, how to ensure SVR2->SW4 cannot be co-opted as a gateway/fwdr but only works point to point between 2 machines, so that SVR traffic on SW4 won't bridge/fwd via PC/SWITCH to any other NIC/ROUTER/device? Moreso when local subnet is /16 containing both IPs. That's my question - how

Comment: Afaik, SW4 -> SRV2 -> SVR1 shouldn't be possible.  The switch wouldn't know that SVR1 is reachable via SRV2, so it wouldn't send data that way.  As far as traffic originating from the server, you'd have to ensure the program binds to the proper IP otherwise the OS would choose one as it sees fit. For curl in particular this would mean using the `--interface` / `--dns-interface` options.

Comment: If you want one link dedicated to talking to a specific PC and they are both on the same switch then a private subnet via a static configuration should work also.

Answer (score 0):

While in principle your switch should figure out from the MACs of NIC1 and NIC2 (which do need different addresses, of course) which path the packet should go, and shouldn't send it to the along the other path, to make absolutely sure (and as you want to learn new things) I'd set up [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN)s to totally separate the data paths.

PfSense [supports](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/VLAN_Trunking) VLANs, so your switch should, too. Roughly speaking, a VLAN packet is like a normal Ethernet packet but with an additional tag field, so you can setup your switch that it acts like several "superimposed" virtual switches. Your switch should also be able to add or remove tags.

So for example, you can have a VLAN with tags `1`, `2` and `3` like this:

```
              Switch           Server

                         tag 1
ROUTER        NIC1  NIC3 ----- NIC1

PC      ----- NIC2  NIC4       NIC2
        tag 1


ROUTER        NIC1  NIC3       NIC1

PC      ----- NIC2  NIC4 ----- NIC2
        tag 2            tag 2


        untag            tag 3     
ROUTER  ----- NIC1  NIC3 ----- NIC1

PC      ----- NIC2  NIC4       NIC2
        tag 3
```

The router is probably not be able to handled tagged VLAN packets.

Make different subnets for the different VLANs, e.g. say 192.168.0.0/24 is subnet the router provides (tag 3), and then 10.0.1.0/24 and 10.0.2.0/24 are the subnets for tag 1 and tag 2.

You can use `ip` to add VLANs to network interfaces, and set addresses So e.g. for your server with `eth1` and `eth2`, you'd do

```
ip link add link eth1 name vlan1 type vlan id 1
ip link add link eth2 name vlan2 type vlan id 2
ip link add link eth1 name vlan3 type vlan id 3
ip addr add 10.0.1.10/24 dev vlan1
ip addr add 10.0.2.10/24 dev vlan2
ip addr add 192.168.0.10/24 dev vlan3
```

You can tell some applications, e.g. Samba, only to bind to specific interfaces, e.g. `vlan3`; or you can create network namespaces, and say put `vlan1` into that namespace and run `sshd` in that namespace. And so on.

VLAN tagging does have some overhead, though your switch should in principle be able to do it in hardware, so also experiment with speeds when only using untagged packets.